# Git SSH access setup issue

Tags: git, bash, ssh

I am currently using Cywin and had a set up working previously. Upon reinstall and redoing my setup it is no longer working.

I am following the instructions here

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

I have modified my .bashrc with the following code

```
SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/environment"

# start the ssh-agent
function start_agent {
    echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
    # spawn ssh-agent
    ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "$SSH_ENV"
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 "$SSH_ENV"
    . "$SSH_ENV" > /dev/null
    ssh-add
}

# test for identities
function test_identities {
    # test whether standard identities have been added to the agent already
    ssh-add -l | grep "The agent has no identities" > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        ssh-add
        # $SSH_AUTH_SOCK broken so we start a new proper agent
        if [ $? -eq 2 ];then
            start_agent
        fi
    fi
}

# check for running ssh-agent with proper $SSH_AGENT_PID
if [ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ]; then
    ps -ef | grep "$SSH_AGENT_PID" | grep ssh-agent > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    test_identities
    fi
# if $SSH_AGENT_PID is not properly set, we might be able to load one from
# $SSH_ENV
else
    if [ -f "$SSH_ENV" ]; then
    . "$SSH_ENV" > /dev/null
    fi
    ps -ef | grep "$SSH_AGENT_PID" | grep -v grep | grep ssh-agent > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        test_identities
    else
        start_agent
    fi
fi
```

My config file in ~/.ssh/config is as follows

```
Host bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Previously this worked as expected. When I would start up Cygwin I would be prompted for my passphrase and then when doing and ssh-add -l I would show my identity added.

However, now it comes up and says

Initializing new SSH agent...

succeeded

and it then brings me up to my prompt.

When doing and ssh-add -l it shows no identities.

I am wondering if there is some mistake in the bash code which might be causing this issue.

Comment: Verify ~/.ssh/id_rsa is still there.

Comment: I have. I can type in ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa and it works as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not indicate that you were prompted for your passphrase, there is something wrong with your ssh keys.  I get the very same thing you get if I move the ~/.ssh/id_rsa to another file.

You probably have to regenerate the ssh key.

Comment: If I manually type in ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa it comes up and asks me for my key perfectly

Comment: I decided to retry this anyway. I am not sure what voodoo worked. However, regening the key made it start working even though the manual method worked before.